# Problems with form_valid in django

Tags: python, html, django

[image]I am using a CBV in Django with Detail View and FormMixin also the function form_valid to list posts and create comments. But I get the error in the picture when I am trying to create the comments. I also want that the user can create comments only under his name but when I am trying to create comments I get a list of all authors which I can choose.

Here is my view

```
class PostDetail(FormMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class=CommentForm
    fields=['comment']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['commentmodel_list'] = CommentModel.objects.filter(post=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.post=self.model.post
        self.object.save()
        return super(PostDetail,self).form_valid(form)
```

Here are my models

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='post_author')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.post)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('dictionary.PostModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_comment')
    comment=models.TextField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='comment_author')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("comment_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Comment: Please share the error, the models, forms, etc.

Comment: I shared them :)

Answer (score 1):

Using both a `form_class` and `fields` makes no sense, since the `fields` are only used to create a `ModelForm` with the [**`modelform_factory`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory). If you thus specify a `form_class`, then that `form_class` should not list unnecessary fields:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = ['comment']
```

Furthermore I would advise to make use of [**`ModelFormMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#modelformmixin) here, since that will remove more boilerplate code. Since your form wraps a `Comment` object, you can not set the object it wraps to `self.object`, since that is a `PostModel` object. You can set the `self.object` as the `PostModel` where you comment on, and then update the `.author` and `.post` of the `.instance` wrapped in the `form`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import ModelFormMixin

class PostDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelFormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['commentmodel_list'] = CommentModel.objects.filter(post=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = self.object
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You might want to call `str(…)` when you define the `__str__` of the model objects:

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post)


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.comment)
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`PostModel`</s> to `Post`.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: thank yoy but now I am getting an error that indicates that:                                                
 __str__ returned non-string (type PostModel)

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: likely in your `PostModel` (or comment model,etc.), you implemented `__str__` the wrong way. But since you did not share that, it is hard to tell :)

Comment: thanks, but I am getting errors all the time :) now I got an error :maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: I would advise to take a look at the traceback. A maximum recursion usually means a function calls itself, without every stopping to do so.

Comment: Main cause: you call `self.method()` when you meant to call `super().method()`.